# How to create a U-boot Image?

Tags: u-boot

I have U-Boot source files and GCC-4.9.3 and I want to create U-Boot image for wandboard and I am using following commands:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"address of arm-none-eabi"
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- 
export ARCH=arm
make wandboard_quad_defconfig
make all
```

Its not working and its giving Following error:

```
make: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: arm-none-eabi-gcc: command not found
dirname: missing operand
```

Answer (score 0):

Do: `file arm-none-eabi-gcc`
If it says something like `ELF 32-bit LSB executable` and you are using a 64-bit machine, you might have missing 32-bit dynamic lib see this similar problem [Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183052&page=2&s=bac07af31493381653082a1bbb0a69b7). Other than looking for the 32-bit library you could use an existing 32-bit machine if you have one.